# Trouble copying folders of images to another folder with Applescript

Tags: applescript, repeat

I'm getting an error about not being able to make alias...to an integer? Not sure...

I'm trying to make this snippet take a handful of folders (in which each has a bunch of images) and copy the contents to an archive drive.

```
on open droppedItems

    set user to do shell script "whoami"
    set archivePath to "/Users/" & user & "/Desktop/Archive' 'Drive"

    #tell application "Finder" to set jobName to name of item droppedItems
    #I need to figure this out as it's not working the way I originally had it

    tell application "Finder"
        do shell script "mkdir -p " & archivePath & "/" & jobName & "RAW' 'FILES"
        set localDestination to archivePath & "/" & jobName & "RAW' 'FILES"
        do shell script "open " & localDestination
        activate
        set position of window 1 to {1000, 0}
    end tell

    **#this is where I'm having issues (obviously)**
    repeat with i from 1 to count of droppedItems
        set currentItem to item i of droppedItems
        #display dialog (currentItem)
        duplicate currentItem to localDestination #I've tried a few different things here...
    end repeat
end open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in the code.

The most significant are

1. `droppedItems` is a **list** of items. To get the name you have to use one item.
2. The Finder accepts only HFS paths (colon separated) and you are even trying to duplicate the files to a literal string. With an HFS path you don't need to escape the space characters. In the `do shell script` line the path is escaped with `quoted form of`.
3. The `duplicate` command belongs to the Finder. It must be wrapped in a `tell application "Finder"` block.

The Finder window is irrelevant. You can duplicate the items without an open window. However I added a line to open the folder. And you don't need a repeat loop either.

```
on open droppedItems

    set archivePath to (path to desktop as text) & "Archive Drive"
    tell application "Finder" to set jobName to name of first item of droppedItems
    set localDestination to archivePath & ":" & jobName & "RAW FILES"
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of localDestination
    tell application "Finder"
        duplicate droppedItems to folder localDestination
        open folder localDestination
    end tell

end open
```

If you want to duplicate only the contents of folders you need indeed a repeat loop

```
on open droppedItems

    set archivePath to (path to desktop as text) & "Archive Drive"
    tell application "Finder" to set jobName to name of first item of droppedItems
    set localDestination to archivePath & ":" & jobName & "RAW FILES"
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of localDestination
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with anItem in droppedItems
            if class of anItem is folder then
                duplicate every item of anItem to folder localDestination
            else
                duplicate anItem to folder localDestination
            end if
        end repeat
        open folder localDestination
    end tell

end open
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian for the info. It definitely works!
I am curious though - The folders that I drop are all part of a parent folder (which is where I wanted to get the jobName from).
Is there a way to get the name of the parent folder of those nested folders?